# How to call a virtual function from a pointer to a parent class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I am trying to call a virtual function from a pointer to a class from within another class. No matter what I do it just calls the original function. I think I am missing something simple. Here are is the smallest bit of code that reproduces the problem. Binary and LiteralExpression inherit from Expr. They each implement their own accept method.

```
template <typename T>
class LiteralExpression;

template <typename T>
class Unary;

template<typename T>
class Visitor {
public:
    virtual T visitLiteralExpressionExpr(LiteralExpression<T> expr) { T temp;  return temp; };
    virtual T visitUnaryExpr(Unary<T> expr) { T temp;  return temp; };
};

template<typename T>
class Expr {
public:
    virtual T accept(Visitor<T>* visitor) { std::cout << "base accept" << std::endl;  T temp; return temp; };
};

template<typename T>
class Unary : public Expr<T> {
public:
    Unary(Token oper, Expr<T> right) : oper(oper), right(&right) { }

    T accept(Visitor<T>* visitor) {
        std::cout << "unary accept" << std::endl;
        return visitor->visitUnaryExpr(*this);
    }

    Token oper;
    Expr<T> *right;
};

template<typename T>
class LiteralExpression : public Expr<T> {
public:
    LiteralExpression(Literal lit, TokenType type) : lit(lit), type(type) { }

    T accept(Visitor<T>* visitor) {
        std::cout << "literal accept" << std::endl;
        return visitor->visitLiteralExpressionExpr(*this);
    }

    Literal lit;
    TokenType type;
};
```

Here I test if the right accept methods are being called. I build a Unary expression object with a negative sign and a LiteralExpression object as it's right "leaf". If I call the unary expression's accept everything works fine, and if I call the LiteralExpression's accept method directly it works fine as well. But if I try to call the LiteralExpression's accept method through a pointer to it as an Expr object it calls the base accept method instead.

```
void AstPrinter::test()
{
    LiteralExpression<std::string> lit(Literal(123), INTEGER);
    Unary<std::string> unary(Token(MINUS, "-", Literal(true), 1), lit); // -123

    lit.accept(this);          // prints "literal accept"
    unary.accept(this);        // prints "unary accept"
    unary.right->accept(this); // prints "base accept"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! (ignore the unencapsulated/non-const instance data, that's just for debugging stuff)

Comment: Where is the code for `Unary`?

Comment: [Code does not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4VAaFI1Y61XERuP2), please fix.

Comment: sorry about that, accidentally pasted the code for the wrong type of expression. Also added the base visitor class at the top.

Comment: The information you've provided is incomplete (e.g. references to types that aren't defined). But you may get the compiler to give diagnostics that will help you find your problem (on your actual code) by (1) specify the function as pure virtual in the base class (there is nothing stopping you defining a pure virtual function) and (2) when overriding it, use the `override` identifier. Assuming your problem isn't a dangling pointer, I suspect you passing an object of the derived class by VALUE as a base, so getting object slicing   (my suggestions will trigger diagnostics on the latter)

Answer (score 2):

```
Unary(Token oper, Expr<T> right) : oper(oper), right(&right) { }
```

This initializes the field `right` to point to the constructor argument `right`. When the constructor exits, the arguments are destroyed and the field `right` becomes a dangling pointer.

The type of the argument should be `Expr<T>&` or `Expr<T>*`.